# How to check whether textbox have at least 2 letter OR not in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a textbox and I want to have at least 2 letter validation.

I have below code and in which user can insert white space and insert data into the database.

But I want a user at least enter 2 valid letters (char/number) then only he can insert them into the database.

```
 var data = $("#intials").val();
            if (data) {
               //OK  Inseert value in DB
            }
            else {
                alert('please insert value in intials box.');
            }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Numbers aren't letters.

Comment: `if (data.length >= 2)`?

Comment: If you want to exclude whitespaces just remove them . `if (data.replace(/\s/g,'').length > 1) { ... } ` Keep in mind that regardless if the user enters `char` ( string ) or a number, the typeof of the input text value is still string.

Comment: Thanks @MihaiT but I want only letters.

Comment: you said ` 2 valid letters (char/number)` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to do it if you want to be sure the initials are either letters or numbers and are at least 2 characters/numbers long. BTW - I thought maybe `intials` was a typo so I changed it to `initials`

```
let data = $("#initials").val().trim().replace(/[^0-9a-zA-Z]/gi, '');
if (data.length >= 2) { 
  // good to go
  // data is the value of $("#initials") minus any extra whitespace and without any punctuation
} else { 
  alert('please insert at least 2 letters (and/or) numbers in the intials box.'); 
}
```